# Why I'm not able to access google analytics in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-analytics, react-ga

I am trying to enable google analytics with the help to `react-ga` hook.

I folloed their docs on [github](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga), I don't know why I'm not getting any data and don't know how can I debug this. I've paste this `ReactGA.initialize("G-NHW4EP16PN");` code on every page but still I'm not getting anything, and also Stream configurations in my Firebase app.

```
import ReactGA from "react-ga";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    ReactGA.initialize("G-NHW4EP16PN");
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
    console.log(window.location.pathname);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingWait src={LoadImg} />}>
        <Router>
          <Sidebar />
          <Switch>
            <Route component={Overview} path="/" exact={true} />
            <Route component={Work} path="/work" />
            <Route component={Services} path="/services" />
            <Route component={Contact} path="/contact" />
            <Route component={PageNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[react-ga README](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/blob/master/README.md)

[image]

The initialize method takes a universal analytics gaTrackingID as its first parameter.  You are sending it G-NHW4EP16PN, which not a universal analytics tracking id.  I would check your account again you appear to be trying to send it a GA4 measurement id instead.

```
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01', {
  debug: true,
  titleCase: false,
  gaOptions: {
    userId: 123
  }
});
```

Comment: How do I find that Universal tracking id, I searched for tracking id in my analytics account and I got G-NHW4EP16PN. Also I searched in my admin settings in tag installation its showing me 
Stream configurations in Firebase.

Comment: That's because you have a GA4 account and not an universal analytics account.    You need to create a universal analytics account instead.  or use the other project https://github.com/unrealmanu/ga-4-react